# Magento 2: Ui Component

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

How can I place double quotes around my title: when a user deletes a record from the select drop down in the Admin Grid-the modal pop up should display my title as double quoted

**i.e
1.  Delete "XYZ"**

**2**. **Are you sure you wan't to delete a "XYZ" record?**

```
'title' => __('Delete ${ $.$data.store_name }'),
                        'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a ${ $.$data.store_name } record?')
```

Comment: have you tru with, 'Delete \"${ $.$data.store_name}\"'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use below solutions for your issue,

```
'confirm' => [
    'title' => __('Delete \"${ $.$data.store_name }\"'),
    'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a \"${ $.$data.store_name }\" record?')
             ]
```

Answer (score 3):

To add **Double Quotes** around your  title you need to **pass "" (double quotes)** with your code :

**Try below code :**

```
                    'confirm' => [
                        'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.store_name }"'),
                        'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a "${ $.$data.store_name }" record?')
                    ]
```